# Android List View forceclosing

Tags: android, listview

I'm learning to build UIs in android, am trying to learn to use ListViews now. I saw the d.android.com tutorial, but it uses ListActivity instead of using a ListView in an Activity.

So I started to experiment, but my application is gets force closed. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/theList"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/label" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListTest.java:

```
public class ListTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String items[] = {"harry", "tony", "solo"};

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_item, items));

    }
}
```

I'm a beginner with android, and I'm not able to find anything obviously wrong with this code. Any help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Post the error log from your `LogCat` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're using `ArrayAdapter` to fill data inside YOUR `row_item`.

`ArrayAdapter` will work as long as you're using the builtin layouts provided by Android.

So,

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

This should work, report back if it doesn't with logcat details.

If you do insist on using your own `row_item` layout for the rows, you will have to make your [custom adapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071253/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/08/custom-view-in-your-listactivity-and.html).

**Update 20th Sept,2012** : If your layout only has one textview then you can still use the vanilla ArrayAdapter, In this constructor

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`

the `int resource` is the `R.layout.row_item` and `int textViewResourceID` is the `R.id.label` of the textview you intend to display your data in.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i know where you have made mistake. In main.xml file, in ListView change the line from **android:id="@+id/theList"** to following,

```
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

also change this line **public class ListTest extends Activity {** to following,

```
public class ListTest extends ListActivity {
```

try this, it will work.

If you want to know about the listview, here is the nice article, http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/.

Comment: It's not necessary, since he's using an `Activity`, if he was using a `ListActivity`, your answer would hold.

Comment: if you only want to use "Activity", then you can't use lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_item, items)); because it will generate error.

Comment: I know, i answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html),

"To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want. "

So, you need to give your own custom ArrayAdapter class, and set it to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an array of strings you can use this code :

Your main.xml file should look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Inside MainActivity Class :

```
public class ListviewExample extends Activity
{

private ListView lv1;
private String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)

{
super.onCreate(icicle);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
}
}
```

Comment: However if you want custom list view, just like your post, see example [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_different) in this article.